# v-data-table problem showing nested object values

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-data-table and I am trying to display my API response objects which hold nested objects. I can not figure out how to display- or better generate the headers properly so it gets displayed as intended.

My objects "items" have this structure.

```js
  {
    "createdAt": "2022-11-22T21:30:37.375Z",
    "exchangeId": "binance",
    "marketId": "BTCUSDT",
    "symbol": "BTC/USDT",
    "timeframe": "1m",
    "cache_size": 1172,
    "analytics": [
      {
        "name": "Candle",
        "description": "Candle OHLCV Data",
        "result": {
          "open": "16542.98000000",
          "high": "16545.42000000",
          "low": "16541.88000000",
          "close": "16543.29000000",
          "volume": "30.66245000"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "RSI",
        "description": "Relative Strength Index",
        "options": {
          "period": 14
        },
        "result": 56.85
      },
      {
        "name": "SMA",
        "description": "Simple Moving Average",
        "options": {
          "period": 200
        },
        "result": null
      },
      {
        "name": "EMA",
        "description": "Exponential Moving Average",
        "options": {
          "period": 200
        },
        "result": 16516.313074314254
      },
      {
        "name": "WMA",
        "description": "Weighted Moving Average",
        "options": {
          "period": 200
        },
        "result": 16525.669004477615
      },
      {
        "name": "ATR",
        "description": "Average True Range",
        "options": {
          "period": 14
        },
        "result": 13.516090980721321
      },
      {
        "name": "MFI",
        "description": "Money Flow Index",
        "options": {
          "period": 14
        },
        "result": null
      },
      {
        "name": "OBV",
        "description": "On Balance Volume",
        "options": {},
        "result": "NaN139.2897100030.66245000"
      },
      {
        "name": "ROC",
        "description": "Rate Of Change",
        "options": {
          "period": 9
        },
        "result": 0.15504598708777856
      },
      {
        "name": "CCI",
        "description": "Commodity Channel Index",
        "options": {
          "period": 20
        },
        "result": null
      },
      {
        "name": "BBands",
        "description": "Bollinger Bands",
        "options": {
          "period": 20,
          "stdDev": 2
        },
        "result": {
          "middle": 16103.22649999999,
          "upper": 16113.265494521354,
          "lower": 16093.187505478625,
          "pb": 1.1431670010640795
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "MACD",
        "description": "Moving Average Convergence/Divergence",
        "options": {
          "fastPeriod": 12,
          "slowPeriod": 26,
          "signalPeriod": 9,
          "simpleMAOscillator": false,
          "simpleMASignal": false
        },
        "result": {
          "MACD": 1.141056311706052,
          "signal": -2.4311417796944026,
          "histogram": 3.5721980914004545
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Pattern Detection",
        "description": "Pattern Detection",
        "bullish_patterns": [],
        "bearish_patterns": []
      }
    ]
  }
```

Up until I have to somehow add the "analytics" properties to the headers I am okay. But I can not figure out how to generate and display the headers properly with nested objects of this structure. Here was my attempt which shows all analytics values in the same column..

```js
  getHeaders() {
      const headers = [
        {
          text: "exchange",
          align: "start",
          value: "exchangeId",
          class: "text-uppercase",
        },
        {
          text: "symbol",
          align: "start",
          value: "symbol",
          class: "text-uppercase",
        },
        {
          text: "timeframe",
          align: "start",
          value: "timeframe",
          class: "text-uppercase",
        },
      ];

      if (this.items[0] && this.items[0].analytics.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 1; i < this.items[0].analytics.length; i++) {
          headers.push({
            text: this.items[0].analytics[i].name,
            align: "start",
            value: "analytics",
            class: "text-uppercase",
          });
        }
      }

      return headers;
```

```js
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="getHeaders()" :items="items">
    <template v-slot:[`item.analytics`]="{ item }">
      <div v-for="a in item.analytics" :key="a.name">
        {{a.name}}
      </div>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Comment: Technically it's not possible because analytics itself array of objects. you can group headers but in vuetify this option is not available.
For reference, you can see element ui group headers
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#grouping-table-head

Comment: too bad, thank you tho